# Can't login on SO/SU/SF/... with stackexchange openID

Tags: bug, status-norepro, openid, google-chrome

I have a stackexchange openID account and a myOpenID account, as well. I never managed it to login with the stackexchange, while myOpenID works.
I go to https://serverfault.com/users/login and click on the stackexchange picture and then nothing happens. There are the three pulsing dots, which just pulse forever.

I am using Chrome on Windows 7 (different computers). When I was using internet explorer just to give it a try there, I got a certificate error ("Internet Explorer blocked this webpage from displaying content with security certificate errors."). When I click on "Show content" it works. So it seems that Chrome hides this error from me.

I am wondering, because Chrome is a widely used browser, but I was not able to find any related questions here on Meta, nor any advice how to deal with the problem.

I assume I could try to import the certificate from stackexchange.com, but is this the preferred way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce this using Internet Explorer, nor Firefox or Chrome.

The *.stackexchange.com certificate appears as so to me:

[image]

Have your trusted root certificates been muddled with perhaps?

Comment: It could be a temporary issue.. I remember that Chrome once blocked a Google service--on looking into the certificate it had a cyclic path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really seems that the `DigiCert High Assurance EV root` can not be validated. Since I am here in the company's network it might be a local policy ... but I am not sure why DigiCert is not trusted ...